# Drupal7: show 404 page after checks in preprocessing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-preprocess

I have some checks in my preprocessing files for nodes. If one of them is true I would like to show my defined 404 page. How is this possible with a php call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
if([YOUR_CHECKS]){
    drupal_not_found();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the drupal_not_foun() function